# Is there a way to resume a cancelled IProgressDialog

Tags: windows, com, progressdialog

In some cases, if the user clicks on the Cancel button of an `IProgressDialog`, I would like to ask for confirmation and resume if the user changed their mind. Is that possible? I've tried resuming the `Timer` and also resetting the `Progress` but the dialog wouldn't resume.

Comment: Just close the dialog and immediately open another one, with progress set to where the previous one left off.

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik. I will use your suggestion if there is no other way because it has the side effect of resetting the time estimation of the first dialog.